# Fish shell - syntax for creating a switch statement which checks against an array of values

Tags: fish

I'm studying the RBENV codebase, and I see that [on line 116 of the `rbenv-init` file](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/c4395e58201966d9f90c12bd6b7342e389e7a4cb/libexec/rbenv-init#L116), a function is created which contains a `switch` statement.  My hypothesis is that we check whether the value of the `command` variable is one of the members of the array of values in the `commands` (plural) variable.  If it is, we execute branch 1 of the switch statement.  Otherwise, we execute branch 2.

I wanted to write a simple script to test my hypothesis, so I wrote the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env fish

set command "foo"

switch $command
case ${argv[*]} 
  echo "command in args"
case "*" 
  echo "command not found"
end
```

However, when I run this script, I get the following error:

```
$ ./foo bar baz

./foo (line 6): ${ is not a valid variable in fish.
case ${argv[*]} 
      ^
warning: Error while reading file ./foo
```

I was expecting `argv` to evaluate to an array containing `bar` and `baz`, since those are the two args I provide to the script.  My syntax matches that of line 117 in the source code (i.e. `case ${commands[*]}`).

The shell I'm executing the script in is zsh v5.8.1, however my shebang specifically references the 'fish' shell so I'd think my shell wouldn't matter.  I have fish v3.5.1 installed, fwiw.

Comment: Pay attention to backslashes in there. Notice how some of the `$` are prefixed with one, and then make it to the fish code and some aren't which means they're expanded (by bash) before making it to the fish code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bash code in there is:

> ```
> commands=(`rbenv-commands --sh`)
> ```

That's split+glob applied to the output of `rbenv-commands --sh` and the resulting words assigned to elements of the `$commands` **`bash`** array

> ```
> case "$shell" in
> fish )
>   cat <<EOS
> function rbenv
>   set command \$argv[1]
>   set -e argv[1]
>   switch "\$command"
>   case ${commands[*]}
>     rbenv "sh-\$command" \$argv|source
>   case '*'
>     command rbenv "\$command" \$argv
>   end
> end
> EOS
>   ;;
> ```

`cat << EOS...` outputs some `fish` code, but as that `EOS` is not quoted, expansions (by bash) are still performed. Except when there's a backslash in front, `$param` is expanded by `bash`. You'll notice that most `$`s are prefixed with a `\`, but not `${commands[*]}` (which anyway is Korn shell syntax, not fish syntax). That's expanded by bash to the elements of the `$commands` array joined with the first character of `$IFS` (space by default).

So the fish code that that `cat` command produces is rather like:

```
function rbenv
  set command $argv[1]
  set -e argv[1]
  switch "$command"
  case elements of the commands bash array
    rbenv "sh-$command" $argv|source
  case '*'
    command rbenv "$command" $argv
  end
end
```

To check whether a string is among a list, you'd use `fish`'s `contains` buitin:

```
set list foo bar baz
set string foo
if contains -- $string $list
  echo $string is in the list
end
```

(like zsh's `if (( $list[(Ie)$string] ))` or for non-empty lists `if [[ $string = (${(~j[|])list}) ]]`)

You can also do:

```
switch $string
  case $list
    echo $string matches at least one of the patterns in the list
end
```

(which is not the same unless none of the elements of the list contain `*` or `?` characters)

(that's more like `zsh`'s `[[ $string = (${(j[|])~list}) ]]` (for non-empty lists)).

There's also:

```
if string match -q -- $pattern $list > /dev/null
  echo at least one of the elements of the list matches $pattern
end
```

(like `zsh`'s `if (( $list[(I)$pattern] ))`).

Comment: In retrospect, I think my confusion was in mentally juggling the bash parameter expansion with fish syntax.  This made it hard for me to tell which was which in this script.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also, I just read who you are.  Thank you for your service with the "Shell Shock" exploit!

Comment: Using a `case` with multiple words will *also* check if the switch argument is in that list. `case foo bar baz` is also true for foo, bar and baz. So this does in fact check for known commands.

Comment: @faho, d'oh you're right, the `IFS='|'` is for another section of the code there, my bad. I'll fix that.